# Responsive design OpenLayers - Bootstrap or Foundation

Tags: openlayers-2, bootstrap-framework

I'm looking to use ZURB Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap with my map app, but before I pick a platform I was trying to find out if people had done this already. It seems lots of people have had issues making the OL maps responsive. Full screen maps seem to work but my maps are in a container with a header and side nav.

Has anyone successfully made their maps responsive?

We have been using JavaScript on window resize but its horribly slow, so I've removed that code and don't really want to use JavaScript if I can do it with responsive design, or do I need to wait until version 3 of OpenLayers?

Suggestions on RD framework welcomed too.

Comment: I am not familiar with zurb foundation or twitter bootstrap. I do display OL maps across devices. I put my map inside a absolutely positioned container and use media queries to adjust the display. #map-container{ 
 position:absolute;
 top: xx%;
 left: yy%;
 width: aa%;
 height: bb%;} and #map{
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

Comment: I am now using bootstrap. here is the css and html i am now using    html,body { height:100%;}

#body{
 height:100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

#content{ height:80%;}

#map-container { height:100%;}

#map {height: 100%;}

<main class="row" id="content">
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-11">
 <div id="map"></div>
</div>
</main>